# Cursor disappears on Firefox Mac and doesn't reset

Tags: javascript, css, macos, firefox, osx-elcapitan

I was developing a webpage where I need to hide cursor in a particular region(div) and display custom cursor in another region.
It works perfectly on all browsers, but just on Firefox Mac, the cursor hides and never comes back. I have taken out the piece of code which is causing this problem ([JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ze572eb5/1/)).

```
$( "#left" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
    leftDiv.style.cursor = "none";
    console.log("Left - " + leftDiv.style.cursor);
});

$( "#right" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
    rightDiv.style.cursor = "url('http://cur.cursors-4u.net/cursors/images11/cur1047.png'), auto";
    console.log("Right - " + rightDiv.style.cursor);
});
```

Here is how it can be reproduced -
Try to move the cursor continuously between blank and text region, at some point the cursor disappears totally and can't be seen at all. Is this fixable with some work around? I see a bug reported on firefox [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720233)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using "none" property for hiding cursor, if we use an URL with a fallback as "auto" it worked.

```
$( "#left" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
leftDiv.style.cursor = "url('http://www.jholjhaal.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/HiddenCursor.cur'), auto";
console.log("Left - " + leftDiv.style.cursor);
});

$( "#right" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
rightDiv.style.cursor = "url('http://cur.cursors-4u.net/cursors/images11/cur1047.png'), auto";
console.log("Right - " + rightDiv.style.cursor);
});
```

And the problem with this approach is that, if the resource specified in the url is not present then the browser's default cursor would show up instead of hiding.